# Updating attributes of Dynamically Generated elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, dynamically-generated

Hmm hi guys, so I have a problem with updating attributes of some Dynamically Generated Elements. The thing is, they are not exactly dynamically generated using javascript DOM e.g. 'document.createElement("image")', rather I have two small .PHP files that already contain all the tags and elements (with .classes and #IDs for stylng etc) that have to be shown, and when the appropriate click happens, either file is 'loaded' inside a designated DIV with id "DIV_load_aceptor". Also to add to the difficulty(?) even the Buttons_1 and _2 , and the #DIV_load_aceptor are all dynamically generated. (same way, a file that gets loaded into a 'super-div'.

The dynamically generated (rather .load()-ed) HTML segment in consideration is:

```
<button id="Button_1">Image</button>
<button id="Button_2">Data</button>

<DIV id="DIV_load_aceptor">
    // PHP Files are loaded here
</DIV>
```

the two PHP files that will get loaded are:

```
<DIV id="Image_Container">                 //1. FILE_IMAGE.PHP
    <img id="First_Image" src="">
    <label id="filename"></label>
    <label id="filetype"></label>
    <label id="filesize"></label>
</DIV>
```

```
<DIV id="User_Container">                 //2. FILE_USER.PHP      
    <img id="Another_Image" src="">
    <label id="Username"></label>
    <label id="USertype"></label>
    <label id="Useremail"></label>  
    //more elements, could be anything, this is just a simple example.  
</DIV>
```

The Jquery/Javascript combo is

```
$("#Button_1").click(function(){
    $("#DIV_load_aceptor").load("FILE_IMAGE.PHP");
    
    aj = new XMLHttpRequest();  ///ajax to get some more details for attributes     
    {//aj readystate checks 
                
        var DATA_ = JSON.parse(aj.responseText);
        $("#First_Image").attr("src", DATA_.IMG_SRC);
        $("#filesize").html(DATA_.IMG_SIZ); 

        //etc etc
    }
    aj.open("post", "DATABASE_QRY_IMG_details_Json_return",true);
    aj.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    aj.send(some data);
});

$("#Button_2").click(function(){
    $("#DIV_load_aceptor").load("FILE_USER.PHP");
    
    aj = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    {   var DATA_  = JSON.parse(aj.responseText);
        $("#Another_Image").attr("src", DATA_.IMG_SRC);
        $("#Username").html(DATA_.UNAME);
        
        //etc etc
    }
    aj.open("post", "DATABASE_QRY_USER_Json_return",true);
    aj.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    aj.send(some data);
});
```

No surprize its not working.. the Attributes of the elements and tags inside the small PHP files are not updating. The thing is, the tags inside the small PHP files are quite a lot (the above code is just a condensed version to illustrate the problem. ) thats why if I go on creating them one by one using javascript it will take quite some time (and get tedious). Is there a way to update these element properties? How do I attach elements to the DOM when they are loaded from files?

Comment: You're already using jQuery. Then why don't you use `$.ajax()`? o.O

Comment: You might want to have a look at what [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load) does (_"ow do I attach elements to the DOM when they are loaded from files?"_).

Comment: Hi @Andreas yes I can use $.ajax as well, thing is was writing AJAX function to send a javascript fileData() object, where I had some problems sending the filedata obj as data paramater using $.post, so someone suggested I use simple javascript Ajax. This is part of that code. i want to understand the Dynamic element attribute updating.. will using $.ajax() help in that directly?